# Functions in document.ready is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I think the Jquery syntax IM using isn't correct, but not sure what is wrong. Maybe someone can give me a hand. So I have a HTML Login page, where it asks for user and pw. I want to save these 2 variables as session cookie.

Here is the HTML of the login:

```
            <FORM NAME="cf">
                <span class="auto-style1">Username:</span> 
                <input type="hidden" id="messageType" name="messageType" value="3">
                <INPUT TYPE="text" id="userName" NAME="userName" size="20" style="width: 180px">
                <br><span class="auto-style1">Password:</span> <INPUT TYPE="password" id="password" NAME="password" size="20" style="width: 180px">
                <span lang="en-ca">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
            </FORM>
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" Value="Sign In" style="width: 109px" class="auto-style2">
```

Here is the Javascript I have written:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password
            var messageType = $("#messageType").val();
            var userName = $("#userName").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var YouEntered;
            var YouEntered2;
            var cookie_name1 = "username";
            var cookie_name = "password";
            putCookie();
            putCookie2();

            auth(messageType, userName, password);
        });
    });

//Set Cookies username and password
function putCookie() {
if(document.cookie != document.cookie)
{index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name1);}
else
{ index = -1;}

if (index == -1)
{
YouEntered=document.cf.userName.value;
document.cookie=cookie_name1+"="+YouEntered+"; expires=0"; //Expires when Session Ends
}
}

function putCookie2() {
if(document.cookie != document.cookie)
{index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);}
else
{ index = -1;}

if (index == -1)
{
YouEntered2=document.cf.password.value;
document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+YouEntered2+"; expires=0"; //Expires when Session Ends
}
}
```

If I use onclick in the HTML to run the putCookie functions, I can save the cookies, but it won't send to the server.

Any help or reason why it doesn't work is appreciated.

Comment: Any error in console??

Comment: The variable `cookie_name1` is local scope to onClick function, make it global or use as function parameter

Comment: Have you verified that the js file is being loaded? Maybe there's a syntax or path error in your script tag.

Comment: I cant find the cookies saved in my browser. BUT the error message pops up (because Server isnt on right now). So i know that the click function is working. Just not those Putcookie functions.

Comment: How to make a variable global in JS? Im very new to HTML, Im more C/C++/C# guy.

Comment: The scope for the variables are off. Pass the variables into the functions.

Comment: do "function putCookie(cookie_name1){ ...

Comment: pass `cookie_name1 , cookie_name` as argument in  your functions

Comment: What is the point of `if(document.cookie != document.cookie)`?  That `if` statement will always fail.

Comment: OK now it works. I forgot/didn't pass the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your function as

```
function putCookie(cookie_name1) {
    if(document.cookie != your_cookie){
        index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name1);
    }
    else {
        var YouEntered=document.cf.userName.value;
        document.cookie=cookie_name1+"="+YouEntered+"; expires=0"; //Expires when Session Ends
    }
}
```

and should call the function like

```
putCookie(cookie_name1);
```